# DP solution of choosing a subset k of n input numbers, "maximising the spread"

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

Mechanical engineer here with little to no formal training in optimisation. Recently though, I've spent some time looking into optimisation and dynamic programming due to a problem I wanted to solve at work (and for learning purposes).

The problem is as follows: *Given a set of N real numbers and a number k <= N, find the subset of k numbers that "maximizes spread"*

I guess "maximising spread" can mean maximising the minimum distance between all numbers. To me, this looks like textbook minimax, even though I havent found any posts with the same problem.

My attempt to solve it:

$$X_{i,j} = \max\limits_{i=0..k \\ j=i..n}\{\min\limits_{k=0..j}(X_{i-1,k}, A_i - A_k)\}$$

where 
$X_{i,j}$ is the solution for choosing $k$ numbers from the first $i$ input numbers and $A_i$ is the ith number in the input.

I've written an algorithm using dynamic programming with lookup table and "parent pointers" [1](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/lecture-videos/lecture-19-dynamic-programming-i-fibonacci-shortest-paths/). Python solution can be found here: https://pastebin.com/EsEhyChc

So my questions are

1. Have I expressed the problem rigorously?
2. Is my analysis correct?
3. Is my solution correct?

Learning a lot here. Any help and insights are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach that uses integer linear programming.  Maybe you can use it to validate optimality of your DP solution.

First sort so that $A_i < A_j$ if $i < j$.  Let binary decision variable $x_i$ indicate whether the $i$th number is selected.  Let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ represent $x_i x_j$.  The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^N x_i &=k \tag1\\
x_i + x_j - 1 &\le y_{i,j} &&\text{for $i < j$} \tag2\\
z - A_j + A_i &\le (A_N - A_1 - A_j + A_i)(1 - y_{i,j}) &&\text{for $i < j$} \tag3
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces that exactly $k$ numbers are selected.  Constraint $(2)$ enforces $(x_i = 1 \land x_j = 1) \implies y_{i,j} = 1$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $y_{i,j} = 1 \implies z \le A_j - A_i$.

Comment: Wow thanks! Having an alternative to compare and reason about the solution is really educational for me. I'll look into it. Also, I take it my analysis and solution are not strictly horrendous. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't look at your code, but your recursive equation has a few issues.  On the LHS, $i$ and $j$ are fixed, but on the RHS these are dummy indices for the $\max$ operator.  Similarly, $k$ appears fixed in the $\max$ but as a dummy index for the $\min$.The text description of $X_{i,j}$ mentions $k$ and $i$ but not $j$.  I think you are correct that DP can be used here, but right now your formula doesn't parse.  You also need some boundary conditions because $i-1$ will be out of bounds when $i=0$.

Comment: You're insights are really helpful. I'll fix the recursive scheme and make sure its sound. I will also run through the integer programming-version and make sure I understand both approaches. Thanks.